# "Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol ..." errors

Tags: fortran, fortran77, g77

I want to compile a makefile containing the following command on ubuntu 32 bit machine.

```
g77 -Wall -c -x f77-cpp-input -Wall
```

But I have some problems I cannot resolve.

```
[gustep.f][1] : In subroutine `gustep':
gustep.f:21: 
           INCLUDE 'gcblocks.inc'
           ^
Unable to open INCLUDE file `[gcblocks.inc][2]' at (^)
gustep.f:122: 
           CUTNEU = 1.0e-8
           ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `cutneu' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:123: 
           IHADR = 5
           ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `ihadr' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:125: 
           IF(NGKINE.GT.0) CALL GSKING(0)
              ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `ngkine' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:129: 
                 IF(GKIN(5,I).EQ.13) THEN
                    ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `gkin' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:140: 
           IF(INWVOL.EQ.1) THEN
              ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `inwvol' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:141: 
               CALL GMEDIA(VECT,NUMED)
                           ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `vect' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:141: 
               CALL GMEDIA(VECT,NUMED)
                                ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `numed' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:144: 
           CALL UHTOC(NAMES(NLEVEL),4,NAME,4)
                      ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `names' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:144: 
           CALL UHTOC(NAMES(NLEVEL),4,NAME,4)
                            ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `nlevel' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:152: 
           IF(ITRA.EQ.TRAK_P) THEN
              ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `itra' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:173: 
                COPY_NO      = NUMBER(NLEVEL-2)
                               ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `number' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
gustep.f:177: 
                DE_P_DEL(M)  = DE_P_DEL(M)+DESTEP*1000.
                                           ^
Invalid declaration of or reference to symbol `destep' at (^) [initially seen at (^)]
In file included from gustep.f:0:
```

Why this declaration is invalid? And how to solve the problem? May
someone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

It's just what the compiler tells you:

```
Unable to open INCLUDE file `[gcblocks.inc][2]'
```

It can't find the file `gcblocks.inc`. The other errors are about missing variable declarations. Probably, these are declared in the missing file. Is `gcblocks.inc` in the current directory? If not, you will need to specify its directory with `-I/path/to/include/dir/`.